# having issues accessing elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm very new to elasticsearch. Using SSH, I've been able to run it via bin/elasticsearch and if I run curl localhost:9200, I can see the details and confirm that it's running. Furthermore, I've installed Marvel and Head, but I'm not sure how to access these GUIs from a browser.

The documentation says to browse to localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel but obviously on our live server this will not work. I've tried replacing localhost with my servers IP but I get nothing. Am I missing something?

In response to Drew R. The latest version is installed and it had been restarted after the installation via the shutdown api.

Sudo IP Tables did produce a lot of DROP results, but I can't make sense of that `(This policy will halt a connection to a host without any communication unless there is a target rule that applies.)`

`curl -vv server:9200/_plugin/marvel` returned:

```
* About to connect() to server port 9200 (#0)
* Trying 50.28.35.72... connected
* Connected to server (50.28.35.72) port 9200 (#0)
> GET /_plugin/marvel HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: server:9200
> Accept: */*
>  
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 74
< 
* Connection #0 to host server left intact
* Closing connection #0
<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/_plugin/marvel/"></head>[root@host2     /usr/share/elasticsearch]# url -vv server:9200/_plugin/marvel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, double-check you've installed marvel:

```
bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

Then restart ES.  Do you see it in the list of plugins in the logs?

If you do, then make sure you aren't blocked from seeing port 9200 outside the machine (`sudo iptables -L`, for example).  If it's AWS, make sure your security group has it open as well.

If it's none of those, what do you get if you run `curl -vv server:9200/_plugin/marvel`?

Comment: That redirect above means you can get to marvel itself okay.  What do you see in the browser?  What does *"but I get nothing"* above mean?

Comment: The 9200 port was closed. I had opened it and everything is working now. Thank you very much for your help.